# JSON object structure

Tags: jquery, json

I am successfully creating a jquery object then saving the object as a json string into a local storage variable using the following code which loops through a list and adds the items to the myObject variable and then saves the object to a local storage variable.

```
var x =$("[name=checklist]").length;
var myObject = {};
myObject.Vehicle_Check = [x];

$("[name=checklist]").each(function(index){
  if (index >0) {
    myObject.Vehicle_Check.push({});
 var PT = $("[name=problemtxt_" + index + "]").val(); //the fault label
 var CL = $("[name=checklbl_" + index + "]").text();    //the question
 var d = $("[name=optiongroup_" + index + "]:checked").val();
    if (d == 'Item 1') { 
      d='OK' 
    }
    else  if (d == 'Item 2') { 
      d='Fault'
        localStorage.setItem('fault', 1);
    }  
  myObject.Vehicle_Check[index].question = CL;
  myObject.Vehicle_Check[index].result = d;
  myObject.Vehicle_Check[index].Fault = PT;
  }  
});

localStorage.setItem('results' ,JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

I have tried to do the same by constructing the object one item at a time saving it to a local storage variable then when I wish to add another item retrieving the object back from the variable  using parseJSON  and adding  an additional  item then saving back to the variable.  I have not got this working correctly.  How should I construct this properly?

```
Initiate the object:

var myObject = {};
myObject.Vehicle_Check = [18];
myObject.Vehicle_Check.push({});
localStorage.setItem('checkobject',JSON.stringify(myObject)); 

Add to the object:

var  myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('checkobject'));
                myObject.Vehicle_Check.push({});
                myObject.Vehicle_Check[I].question = 'First test!';
                myObject.Vehicle_Check[I].result = 'OK';
                myObject.Vehicle_Check[I].Fault = 'none';
             localStorage.setItem('checkobject',JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

Comment: Works fine for me, once i properly define `I`

Comment: Why don't you set a variable to the new sub-object, fill in its properties, and then push it onto the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `I`. You might do something like this instead so you don't have to worry about the index:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.Vehicle_Check = [];
localStorage.setItem('checkobject', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

...

```
var myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('checkobject'));
var next = {
    question: 'First test!',
    result: 'OK',
    Fault: 'none'
};
myObject.Vehicle_Check.push(next);
localStorage.setItem('checkobject', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Edit - This could simplify things even further, depending on your usage:

```
myObject.Vehicle_Check.push({
    question: 'First test!',
    result: 'OK',
    Fault: 'none'
});
```

Comment: Sorry I defined I but had not included the code!  I will have a go with your code, - thanks.